# AWS Amplify DataStore does not update properly (react-native)

Tags: react-native, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-datastore

I am developing react native app with Amplify and using DataStore.
I want to save the user token to DB, so I checked and saved in App.js.

During testing, I noticed that the token often doesn't update. So I tested the token alternately to two different simulators.

Belows are my code

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const updateDeviceToken = async () => {
      console.log('Entering updateDeviceToken');
      if (deviceToken) {
        console.log('deviceToken is present');
        if (dbUser && deviceToken) {
          if (dbUser && dbUser.token !== deviceToken) {
            console.log('auth', deviceToken);
            console.log('dbUser.token', dbUser.token);
            console.log('dbUser.id', dbUser.id);

            try {
              const newUser = await DataStore.query(User, user =>
                user.id.eq(dbUser.id),
              );
              console.log('user1', newUser[0]);

              const dbuser = await DataStore.save(
                User.copyOf(newUser[0], updated => {
                  updated.token = deviceToken;
                }),
              );
              console.log('user2', dbuser);
              setDbUser(dbuser);
            } catch (err) {
              console.err('update token error', err);
            }
          }
        } else {
          console.log('dbUser.token is the same as deviceToken');
        }
      } else {
        console.log('deviceToken is not present');
      }
    };
```

The output log is as follows

```
 LOG  Entering updateDeviceToken
 LOG  deviceToken is present
 LOG  auth tokenaaaaa
 LOG  dbUser.token tokenbbbbb
 LOG  dbUser.id 73e114d0-6c73-40d0-9b18-c015ae9edd8d
 LOG  user1 {....."token": "tokenbbbbb",.....}
 LOG  user2 {....."token": "tokenaaaaa",.....}
```

On the log, the update appears to be normal. But when I check the actual data on the amply console, it doesn't update and still shows 'tokenbbbbbb'.

I really don't know what's the cause.

If anyone has solutions, I'd greatly appreciate detailed explanations.